# Conversion overflow exception while convertion SqlDecimal into System.Decimal

Tags: c#-3.0

//here i am storing some  System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal
`System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal sum= some dedimal value`
while converting it into decimal (`decimal ddd = sum.Value;`) I am getting the error "Conversion Overflow exception".

May anybody help to sort out this problem?

I there any way to create `SqlDecimal` object which is equivalent to `System.Decimal`?